# Powershell: Updating string in hash table

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of custom objects and need to do the following steps for each object:

1. Replace "Team1 Group" with "Team2 Group"
2. Save the resulting update to a hash table, which I will pass to an API

The objects look like this:

```
id             : 1
groupId        : 1
name           : Customer1 Dashboard
fullName       : Customer Dashboards/Team2 Group/Customer1 Group/Customer1 Dashboard
groupName      : Customer1 Group
groupFullPath  : Customer Dashboards/Team2 Group/Customer1 Group
widgetTokens   : { @{type = owned; name = defaultResourceGroup; value = Client Teams/Team1 Group/Customers/Customer1*; inheritList = System.Object[] }, @{type = owned; name = defaultWebsiteGroup; value = Client Teams/Team1 Group/Customers/Customer1; inheritList = System.Object[]}}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Foreach ($dashboard in $allDashboards) {
    $dashboardProperties = @{ }
    $dashboard.psobject.properties | ForEach-Object {         $dashboardProperties[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
@($dashboardProperties.GetEnumerator()) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'widgetTokens' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value | Where-Object { $_.Value -match "Team1 Group" } | ForEach-Object { $dashboardProperties[$_.Key] = @($_.value.replace('Team1 Group', 'Team2 Group')) }
$dashboardProperties
#Code to interact with an API
```

}

Because there are two items that match the "@($dashboardProperties.GetEnumerator()) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'widgetTokens' }..." line (at least, I think that's why), I am getting the following error:

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At line:1 char:200
+ ... ch-Object { $dashboardProperties[$_.Key] = @($_.value.replace('Team1 ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex

    Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
    At line:1 char:200
    + ... ch-Object { $dashboardProperties[$_.Key] = @($_.value.replace('Team1 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

When I run this, I see both lines, as expected:

```
@($dashboardProperties.GetEnumerator()) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'widgetTokens' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value | Where-Object { $_.Value -match "Team1 Group" }
```

I am not sure how to move past this, any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback from Reddit, looks like this should work:

```
$DashboardProperties.WidgetTokens |
Where-Object { $_['Name'] -eq 'widgetTokens' -and $_['Value'] -match 'Team1 Group' } |
ForEach-Object { $_['Value'] = $_['Value'] -replace '1','2' }
```